# What can we infer from the sample size and mean?

Tags: distributions, mean, standard-deviation, sample-size, population

I came across this interesting question today and haven't been able to understand how the statistician was able to arrive at the estimate:

A sample of 300 customers were asked to participate in a survey. The timestamp at which each customer submits their response is recorded and the results are as follows:

- Each of the 300 customers responds within two weeks
- The mean time to response is 107 hours

A statistician analyzes these results and claims that the mean time to response to survey for customers in the future would be between 96.12 and 120.65 hours.

How do you think your he/she arrived at this estimate?

Comment: What additional information would you need to do this in a way you know? What does that $(96.12, 120.65)$ interval look like or remind you of in the statistics you know?

Comment: @Dave, it's the confidence interval right?

Comment: It's somewhat of a poor question because the statistician in this example didn't state how confident his future estimate is.  The statistician is claiming that in the future, the mean response times would be between 96.12 and 120.65, but is he confident that his estimate would be correct 95 times out of 100 in repeated samples, in 90 out 100 theoretical repeated samples in the future, or perhaps just 5% of the time?  This statistician did a poor job of explaining his result. ;-)

Comment: @John, to be fair, we have no idea what this is as there's not confidence level supplied by the "statistician."  For all we know, based on the question, the statistician plucked these two numbers out of thin air.  How on Earth would we know how the statistician arrived as these estimates without a methodology statement of some sort?  This is a fine example of a poor question that accomplishes little to further students' education and only serves to confuse students.  Little learning occurs here.

Comment: I’m mostly with @StatsStudent that the question is not a good one, so I am curious about the source, but it makes for some good discussion with someone just learning statistics. Yes, I think that’s a confidence interval. What missing information do you need to calculate a confidence interval? I count two pieces of missing information, maybe three of you’re being really picky. (The third is if it is a confidence interval based on a t-statistic, but that’s probably the only method you’re expected to know at an introductory level.)

Comment: Yeah, I also agree with @StatsStudent . The question seems to be missing some key information. Does the fact that everyone responds in the first 2 weeks help us in any way?

Comment: That could have an implication to the business, but it doesn’t mean anything to me for constructing a confidence interval. // Let the question leave out key information, though. You fill in the gaps. What else do you need? What are you willing to assume?

Comment: I think they just used the two-weeks to help you understand that all $n = 300$ customers ended up as respondents to the survey (i.e., no missing data), and this would come into play in computing a $T$-statistic and confidence intervals (i.e. $T = {\bar{X}-\mu\over{\hat{\sigma}\over{\sqrt{n}}}}$)

I think what this question is essentially asking you to do is to recognize that the statistician is likely using a prediction interval for his conclusion.  Then you'd need to state how this is computed (even if you don't have all the information) and what assumptions were necessary for it.

Comment: Okay, thank you StatsStudent and Dave!

Comment: @StatsStudent Confidence interval, not prediction interval…this is about the mean.

Comment: Ah yes.  My mistake in a fast write-up.  Thanks for catching this!

Comment: At least we would need to know the future sample size! Maybe they assumed it would be the same.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen For the mean?

Comment: @Dave: Yes! CI for a future mean must depend on the future sam+le size ... as well as the present sample size. Then, assuming a normal approx (which should be adequate here) it is straightforward.

Comment: @Stats Because the interval is not symmetric around the mean, it almost surely was not constructed as a Student t (or even Z) confidence interval.  That precludes using a Normal approximation, too.  But by not specifying a future sample size, the question clearly does ask for a confidence interval and not a prediction interval.

Comment: @whuber correct! I tried to construct it as a student t confidence interval but noticed that the interval is not symmetric around the mean. What other distribution can we think of here?

Comment: @StatsStudent as whuber pointed out, the confidence interval is not symmetric about the mean. If the statistician would have claimed that the mean time to response to survey for customers in the future would be between 96.12 and 117.88, then we could followed your approach. Can you think of any other distribution?

Comment: John, the issue concerns more than a distributional model: the confidence interval results from a particular confidence interval procedure.  It is not possible to reverse-engineer a single confidence interval to deduce either the model or the procedure.  This indicates there are many correct answers.  The question evidently is designed to test the extent of your knowledge of confidence procedures and how you reason about them.  That might be a great interview question, but because of these ambiguities it doesn't work well here on CV.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your response. Do you agree with BruceET's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262247/calculate-the-standard-deviation-from-confidence-interval-sample-size-and-mean/4262376#4262376)?

Comment: It's certainly a reasonable one: an exponential distribution is often a reasonable model for response times.  There are other equally reasonable models, though, such as lognormal; and for the lognormal model, at least, there are many different confidence interval procedures to choose from.

Comment: Okay, thank you again @whuber. Really appreciate your help